# Recuperar contraseña (.NET , AJAX)

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, asp.net, .net

Tengo una página con ingresos correctos conectada a un *SQL Server* para diversas funciones. En el *Default*, tengo un botón de *Acceso a clientes*, que al dar click me abre un formulario de usuario, contraseña para ingresar junto con el botón de Iniciar.

Se agregó una referencia de *Recuperar contraseña* y aquí es donde tengo problemas.

Ya se programaron las *jQuerys* y el *AJAX* para validación y tiempo de ingreso al portal, pero esta referencia de recuperar la *password* no logró llamarla de manera correcta, me muestra *error 404* en un principio y ahora un *error 505*. Se supone que al darle click, abrirá un nuevo cuadro en el cuál ingresaremos el correo, y si coincide con alguno de nuestra base de datos, enviará al correo la contraseña que tiene el acceso.

Código de **default.apx**:

```
function recuperaya() {

    var _usuario = $("#recuperauser").val();
    var _correo = $("#recuperaemail").val();

    var actionData = "{'user': '" + _usuario + "','correo': '" + _correo + "'} ";
    $('#modal-transparent').modal('show');
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: "Default.aspx/Ajaxrecupera",
            data: actionData,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (msg) {
                var respuesta = msg.d;
                var arrayDeCadenas = respuesta.split(",");
                if (arrayDeCadenas[0] == "1") {
                    document.getElementById("menssajesesion").innerText = arrayDeCadenas[1];
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("menssajesesion").innerText = arrayDeCadenas[1];
                }
                $("#myModal").modal("hide");
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("ERROR " + result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Click derecho, inspeccionar elemento, pestaña "Network", intenta reproducir los pasos y presta atención al error 500, selecciona ese, ve a la derecha, "response" y mira lo que devolvió el servidor, con eso tendrás mejores pistas para encontrar el problema

Comment: Amigo, falta un lado importante, tu serverside, la respuesta 500 es respuesta del servidor. Por otro lado, podrías colocar el alert con el result impreso. Para mas comodidad, en un `console.log(result);` quedaría mejor

Comment: Que tecnologia usas para  tu vista MVC asp.net, webforms?, como estas filtrando los permisos para las peticiones de paginas

Answer (score 0):

revisando todas mis paqueterias de archivos, no habia una conexion al correo emisor que tendría que mandar el mensaje al receptor. esto lo realize en el web.config

```
<add key="mailServer" value="mail.servidordecorreo"/>
<add key="mailRemitente" value=usuario@servidordecorreo"/>
<add key="mailPuerto" value="25" />
```

habilite el puerto general para realizar mis pruebas, pero este puerto puede cambiar de acuerdo a la configuracion que tengamos del correo emisor.
y en mi codigo de default.aspx, cree un nuevo modal para pedir la información al usuario que deseaba recuperar su contraseña:

```
<div class="modal modal-transparent fade" id="modal-password" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="form-group text-center">
                                    <div class="dropdown btn-group">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" width="300px;" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                            <img id="imalan2" src="mx.png" />
                                            <span id="sp_Idioma2" runat="server">Idioma</span>
                                            <span class="caret"></span>
                                        </button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="#" id="ban_mex2">
                                                <img id="imalan_es2" src="mx.png" />
                                                <span id="sp_name_lang_mx2">Espa&ntilde;ol</span></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" id="ban_usa2">
                                                <img id="imalan_en2" src="en.png" />
                                                <span id="sp_name_lang_en2">Ingl&eacute;s</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="anchocelda">
                                    <center>
                                        <input type="text" runat="server" class="form-control" id="recuperauser" placeholder="Nombre Usuario" />
                                        <input type="text" runat="server" class="form-control" id="recuperaemail" placeholder="Correo electronico" />
                                        <h4><span id="menssajesesion2" runat="server" class="recupe coloractivo"></span></h4>
                                        <br />
                                    </center>
                                    <br />
                                    <button type="button" id="btnrecupera" runat="server" class="btn-primary form-control" onclick="recuperaya();" style="background-color: #A30133; color:#FFFFFF;">Recuperar Contraseña</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
```

y solo lo referencié con mis funciones ya creadas.